# DIV tag is acting as an INLINE instead of BLOCK

Tags: html, tags

hello im having a issue here im learning HTML and everything is going fine but i have a problem that is making me very angry.

they say that the div tag is a block level element
so anything IN BETWEEN div tags should start with a new line break and end with one.

but as im testing it out this is not true!
and its frustrating me!

heres the raw code

```
<div>this is plain text in a div tag.</div>
<div>this is plain text in a div tag.</div>
<div>this is plain text in a div tag.</div>
<p>This is paragraph that is NOT in a set of div tags.</p>
<div>this is plain text in a div tag.</div>
<div>this is plain text in a div tag.</div>
```

here is how it is displaying! WTF!

```
this is plain text in a div tag
this is plain text in a div tag
this is plain text in a div tag

This is paragraph that is NOT in a set of div tags

this is plain text in a div tag
this is plain text in a div tag
this is plain text in a div tag
```

only the paragraph starts with and ends with a new line break acting as is should because 
it is a block level element

but the "this is a plain text in a set of div tag" lines dont start or end with a new line breaks!
and they are in a set of div tags! which also supposed to be blocks now what am i not understanding!

and the source of where im learning html has a layout example with div tags thats confusing me also
none of the parts in this layout start or end with a new line break!
heres the cold for this also

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="container" style="width:500px">

<div id="header" style="background-color:#FFA500;">
<h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">Main Title of Web Page</h1></div>

<div id="menu" style="background-color:#FFD700;height:200px;width:100px;float:left;">
<b>Menu</b><br>
HTML<br>
CSS<br>
JavaScript</div>

<div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:200px;width:400px;float:left;">
Content goes here</div>

<div id="footer" style="background-color:#FFA500;clear:both;text-align:center;">
Copyright © W3Schools.com</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

only time the occurance of a linebreak was with a h1 tag and he 
used margin-bottom:0 to take the bottom line out
so why are the other sections in this right on top and next to each other as if they were inline elements
when they each are in their own div tag...this is frustrating me ! i want to pull my hair out !

Comment: you need to read up more on block level element vs inline element. And something on default CSS properties of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to understand that some of these html tags especially text containers i.e headers,paragraphs, etc. come with a default margin other than zero. if you are not okay with these spacing's you style them otherwise they just take their default values. 
try adding margins to your paragraph tags to obtain your desired effect

Comment: it is not the paragraph it is acting as it should my my problem is that the other sentences done act the same as a paragraph because they are in div tags...a div and p are both block level elements so why does the paragraph the only one that makes a new line before and after it u see what im saying

Comment: browsers automatically add margin to tags such as <h> and <p> <ul>. but apparently this is not the same with the div tags. my guess is the  developers dont want the rendering of these tags to be all packed up cos some other markups like xml (usually text only) also use it.

Comment: so basically a div tag doesnt ALWAYS start whatever is in it with a new line and end with a new line?

Comment: i guess u have your answer there. A little more research on your own will help you understand these tags better.

Comment: ok last thing i understand the part about the <h> tags <p> and <ul> starting because they are block elements and they are behaving as they should by default....but anything that is put in a div tag shoud by DEFAULT have the same charateristics but its not doing it the same and thats confusing.

Comment: there's probably a reason that browser developers chose them to render that way. and i am sure a lot of standards and compliance's must have been met. but if they don't satisfy you, maybe writing your browser is not out of place.

Comment: just give me one more answer paste this is something where u can render it. why are all of these stacked on top on each other then if div is a true block level element there should be a new line on top and bottom of the div no matter the browswer im using firefox <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

This is some text.

<div style="color:#0000FF">
  This is a heading in a div element
  This is some text in a div element.
</div>

This is some text.

</body>
</html>

Comment: sorry i feel like a idiot now...i just kept fooling with it and i was thinking that the div would make new a line BREAK but it makes a new line not a LINE break thanks bro u helped me

Answer (score 0):

This is not an HTML issue. What you are seeing is a CSS issue. Each browser has a default way of styling elements. It so happens that paragraphs are automatically fitted with some padding/margin.

I took your code, and applied this simple css, which immediately resolved the visual issue:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>CSS Fix</title>
<style type="text/css">
    div, p {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div>this is plain text in a div tag.</div>
    <div>this is plain text in a div tag.</div>
    <div>this is plain text in a div tag.</div>
    <p>This is paragraph that is NOT in a set of div tags.</p>
    <div>this is plain text in a div tag.</div>
    <div>this is plain text in a div tag.</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks kevbot but what i mean is this im thinking the div tag should make the sentence thats not a technical paragraph start and end with a new line just like the real paragraph cause its in a div which is a block element so they all should be spaced on a new line but only the paragraph is u see